# Retrieving APY from PancakeSwap CAKE auto-compounding pool

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap

Looking at the contract from the CAKE auto-compounding pool (https://bscscan.com/address/0xa80240Eb5d7E05d3F250cF000eEc0891d00b51CC#code), it appears there is no direct call for calculating the current APY, as displayed in PancakeSwap (currently 107.11%).

I tried to calculate it retrieving the number of shares owned by a user (contract.userInfo(user_address)[2]/1e18), which gives the amount of cake staked by the user. However, I could not retrieve the expected APY.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/gaijinjoe/cake-liquidity/blob/7ae59f159d09dc3560b294ce8d19955a56f401e5/borrow-limit-status.js#L233

Here you go.

Call it like this:

```
 const autoAPY = compoundInterest(1, cakeSwapPoolAPR / 100, 365 * 288, 1);
```

where `cakeSwapPoolAPR`  is the APR of the Manual CAKE pool. Look at the code to see how to calculate the Manual CAKE pool APR.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very hepful.

Comment: the answer is actually related to the manual coumpounding Cake pool. Any chance there is also a formula for the auto-compounding cake pool?